# Storing facebook token for offline access

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am looking for a way to save the access token to allow the user to post on facebook without having to log in for each call to the graph API :

I require an offline_access token, i store it in the NSUserDefaults, but when i try to use it again i get a FacebookErrDomain error 10000

Here is what i do :

In the fbDidLogin i get the access_token and save it in the user defaults

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSString *token = self.facebook.accessToken;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"facebookToken"];

}
```

After that when i run the app again i just get the token from the user defaults, and assign them to the facebook object :

```
NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"facebookToken"];
[_facebook setAccessToken:token];
```

But it doesn't work..

Has anybody any idea what i could be doing wrong ?

Thanks,
Vincent.

EDIT :
If i do a NSlog after `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"facebookToken"];` i can see that the token was saved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having the same problem and I found out that the issue is you are not storing expiration date.

If you do that, it will allow you to relogin in fine.

Sample code:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_facebook.accessToken forKey:@"fb_access_token"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"fb_exp_date"];
```

Retrieving is the same, just set the `_facebook.expirationDate`.

Answer (score 3):

Ok it seems that it's the facebook iOS SDK which is buggy.

Using the token stored in the user defaults, i can perform a post on my wall using curl :

```
curl -F 'access_token=br69pK_lh0Xbj....plDRUdG97a55KIHzlaiw' \
     -F 'message=TEST API.' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/ME/feed
```

So i just perform a HTTPS POST, so using ASIHTTPRequest  this code works like a charm :

```
NSURL* faceboobUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/ME/feed"];
self.request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:faceboobUrl];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:token forKey:@"access_token"];
[request setPostValue:msg forKey:@"message"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:TIMEOUT];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

No thanks facebook ;)

Vincent

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to call :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

This will "save" your preferences to disk/flash.

Also do an NSLog on the token before you save it to make sure it's not nil.

Comment: Hi, i am sure the Token is saved since i can see it when i get it back from the user defaults. Another thing i noticed is that the token is different each time i log in and ask permissions, dont know if it helps. I updated my questions with these informations