# iPhone/Objective-C - Facebook Single Sign On

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I have implemented single sign on functionality using Facebook's SDK in my iPhone application, however I'm just wondering how you go about detecting whether they've already authenticated and/or accepted permissions?

I noticed that when checking for this the Facebook application always spawns and says you have already authenticated and you're always forced to click Okay, which is quite annoying every time they open the application.

There's an iPhone application called Socialcam that only asks you once to accept the permissions and every time you open the application from that point onwards it knows that you've already been authenticated and never asks you again.

I would like to do this as my application relies heavily on Facebook permissions. It uses their profile picture and checkin permissions (for example) throughout various different areas of my application.

If I go about using the `NSHTTPCookieStorage` :

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]);
```

It provides me this information. How would I go about using it to authenticate against the Facebook Graph API?

```
(
    "<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:@\"datr\" value:@\"5WqaTXRFMRlijBtMvcGg-wS1\" expiresDate:@\"2013-04-06 07:42:45 +0000\" created:@\"323854917.000000\" sessionOnly:FALSE domain:@\".facebook.com\" path:@\"/\" secure:FALSE comment:@\"(null)\" commentURL:@\"(null)\" portList:[]>",
    "<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:@\"locale\" value:@\"en_US\" expiresDate:@\"2011-04-19 09:46:10 +0000\" created:@\"324294323.000000\" sessionOnly:FALSE domain:@\".facebook.com\" path:@\"/\" secure:FALSE comment:@\"(null)\" commentURL:@\"(null)\" portList:[]>",
    "<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:@\"m_user\" value:@\"myfacebookusernameishere%3A105339949%3Anwib6jXhKY2tIYjz%3A0%3Aajax_0%2Cwidth_0%3A1302162165\" expiresDate:@\"2011-07-06 07:42:45 +0000\" created:@\"323854917.000000\" sessionOnly:FALSE domain:@\".facebook.com\" path:@\"/\" secure:FALSE comment:@\"(null)\" commentURL:@\"(null)\" portList:[]>"
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you kept the are you checking the permissions for the user who is logging again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fulvio,

I haven't looked at my Facebook code for 9+ months. Hence, take my answer as a suggestion. That said, I've just reviewed it and the authentication state is maintained in cookies leftover from the authorization process. This is pretty easy to log:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]);
```

Enjoy,
Andrew

Comment: I see, I'll give this a try when I'm at home. I'm assuming this will provide me some sort of access_token, which I can then use to call graph API methods?

Comment: @Andrew Not sure exactly what this is going to mean when I want to call the Graph API methods that require an access_token? I read somewhere about the "m_user" value containing my applications appId but wouldn't I need the actual users access_token in order to make requests? Perhaps some sample code that you are using would help?

Answer (score 1):

cookies are sometimes not helpful so use the below one

```
[facebook requestForGraph:@"me" delegate:self]
```

with new Facebook API

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to try this:

[Storing facebook token for offline access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224579/storing-facebook-token-for-offline-access)