# What to do to avoid having to spend a long time asking for permission every time?

Tags: facebook, acaccountstore

My app ask permission from facebook and twitter to publish and read. The way it works currently is everytime the app is restarted, it simply ask permission again.

The process takes a long time. Most other app don't work that way. How do they do so? I thought I already have token that I can use and I could have saved when that happen.

I thought the process is fast.

Take a look at this code for example

```
[self vSuspendAndHaltThisThreadTillUnsuspendedWhileDoing:^{
    [BGHPTools vDoForeGroundAndWait:^{
        PO (self.ACAccountType);
        PO([self dicReadOptions]);
        [self.ACAstore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:self.ACAccountType options:[self dicReadOptions] completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            self.bPermissionToAccessStoreGranted=granted;
            [self vContinue];
        }];
    }];
}];
```

Most of you are familiar with this part of the code

```
        [self.ACAstore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:self.ACAccountType options:[self dicReadOptions] completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            self.bPermissionToAccessStoreGranted=granted;
            [self vContinue];
        }];
```

That's it. I am asking the Account Framework to grant me permission to read. But I do not want to spend a long time asking for that permission everytime the app restarts.

But that takes time. I want to just use my token and make it fast.

But what about if I am already granted permission? Couldn't Account framework figure that out and grant me permissions more quickly?

Most likely I need to use

```
- (void)renewCredentialsForAccount:(ACAccount *)account completion:(ACAccountStoreCredentialRenewalHandler)completionHandler
```

The problem with renewCredentialsForAccount is some people may have multiple facebook account. The way to know which account is selected or getting the ACAccount object is through

```
     requestAccessToAccountsWithType:self.ACAccountType options:[self dicReadOptions] completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            self.bPermissionToAccessStoreGranted=granted;
            [self vContinue];
        }];
```

Which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Most APIs need some account information and return a token that you add to all following requests and that stays valid for a certain time. You can obviously store that token and how long it is valid, then when the app starts the next time, check if the token is still valid, and if not, request a new token as soon as possible, not only when it is needed. The API won't know that your app has been restarted.

Comment: Yes. How exactly I should do that?

Comment: Why not just save the token in NSUserDefaults, and use the token onload if it is valid?

Comment: Yes. How to do so? How to use token onload?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224579/storing-facebook-token-for-offline-access